# Riscv GCC 4.9.2 can't compile linux 3.14.29

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, version, riscv

when i use riscv gcc(verison 4.9.2) to compile linux(version 3.14.29),i got some error, it seems that gcc cant't recognize some opcode, how can i solve that? change the gcc to version 4.6? thanks

```
root@riscv-VirtualBox:/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29# make ARCH=riscv
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  ......
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h: Assembler messages:
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:22: Error: Instruction csrc requires absolute expression
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:22: Error: Instruction csrc requires absolute expression
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:10: Error: Instruction csrr requires absolute expression
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:22: Error: Instruction csrc requires absolute expression
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:22: Error: Instruction csrc requires absolute expression
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:10: Error: Instruction csrr requires absolute expression
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:16: Error: Instruction csrs requires absolute expression
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:16: Error: Instruction csrs requires absolute expression
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:10: Error: Instruction csrr requires absolute expression
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:16: Error: Instruction csrs requires absolute expression
/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29/arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:16: Error: Instruction csrs requires absolute expression
make[1]: *** [init/main.o] Error 1
make: *** [init] Error 2

root@riscv-VirtualBox:/home/riscv/riscv/linux-3.14.29# riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc --version
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc (GCC) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Are you using the master branch of riscv-tools and the master branch of riscv-linux? (and NOT the master branch of riscv-gnu-toolchain, but whatever commit is pointed to by the riscv-tools master repo).

Comment: yes,i used the master branch of riscv-tools and the master branch of riscv-linux, please see my install step below

Comment: below is my steps to install riscv-tools and linux, is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mismatch in your repositories (this is probably not your fault). You can try and check out the "new_privileged_isa" branches, but the issue is that the RISC-V privilege SPEC (as of 2015 Apr 30) is still in flux and we cannot guarantee that the heads of the branches will all work together.

Comment: thank u, i will try the "new_privileged_isa" branches

Comment: Checking out the "new_privileged_isa" branch worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, i use the following ways to install riscv-tools :

```
git clone https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools.git
git submodule update --init --recursive
./build.sh
```

and use the following ways to get linux source:

```
 curl https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.14.29.tar.xz | tar -xJ 
cd linux-3.14.29 
git init 
git remote add origin https://github.com/riscv/riscv-linux.git 
git fetch 
git checkout -f -t origin/master
```